# How to get the value of an XML node searching by child node value using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

I need to get the value from the following XML the `CodigoImovel == 6124-2` using Nokogiri Gem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Carga xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Imoveis>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>6124-2</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Apartamento</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Apartamento Padrão</SubTipoImovel>
        </Imovel>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>86765</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Apartamento</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Apartamento Padrão</SubTipoImovel>
            <CategoriaImovel>Cobertura</CategoriaImovel>
        </Imovel>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>981768</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Casa</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Casa de Condomínio</SubTipoImovel>
            <CategoriaImovel>Térrea</CategoriaImovel>
        </Imovel>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>357468</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Casa</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Casa de Condomínio</SubTipoImovel>
            <CategoriaImovel>Térrea</CategoriaImovel>
        </Imovel>
        <Imovel>
            <CodigoImovel>587168</CodigoImovel>
            <TipoImovel>Comercial/Industrial</TipoImovel>
            <SubTipoImovel>Conjunto</SubTipoImovel>
            <CategoriaImovel>Comercial/Sala Padrão</CategoriaImovel>
        </Imovel>
    </Imoveis>
</Carga>
```

I am using this to get value
xml.xpath("//Carga//Imoveis//Imovel[CodigoImovel='"+re_code+"']") 
but it says undefined local variable or method `re_code' for #
I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What value does `re_code` hold?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and could evetually get nodes you need:

```
 require 'nokogiri'
 xml = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse '<Carga 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Imoveis>
      <Imovel>
          <CodigoImovel>6124-2</CodigoImovel>
          <TipoImovel>Apartamento</TipoImovel>
          <SubTipoImovel>Apartamento Padrão</SubTipoImovel>
      </Imovel>
      <Imovel>
          <CodigoImovel>86765</CodigoImovel>
          <TipoImovel>Apartamento</TipoImovel>
          <SubTipoImovel>Apartamento Padrão</SubTipoImovel>
          <CategoriaImovel>Cobertura</CategoriaImovel>
      </Imovel>
      <Imovel>
          <CodigoImovel>981768</CodigoImovel>
          <TipoImovel>Casa</TipoImovel>
          <SubTipoImovel>Casa de Condomínio</SubTipoImovel>
          <CategoriaImovel>Térrea</CategoriaImovel>
      </Imovel>
      <Imovel>
          <CodigoImovel>357468</CodigoImovel>
          <TipoImovel>Casa</TipoImovel>
          <SubTipoImovel>Casa de Condomínio</SubTipoImovel>
          <CategoriaImovel>Térrea</CategoriaImovel>
      </Imovel>
      <Imovel>
          <CodigoImovel>587168</CodigoImovel>
          <TipoImovel>Comercial/Industrial</TipoImovel>
          <SubTipoImovel>Conjunto</SubTipoImovel>
          <CategoriaImovel>Comercial/Sala Padrão</CategoriaImovel>
      </Imovel>
  </Imoveis>
</Carga>'
```

mind single quote after parse and at the end. Then I did this

```
re_code = '6124-2'
xml.xpath("//Carga//Imoveis//Imovel[CodigoImovel='"+re_code+"']")
```

And got the first `<Imovel>` node with child nodes in return. Although I am not sure why you called it `re_code`, did you mean to use regular expressions here?